# Loading values stored in .json file

Tags: json, angular

I want to read the configuration values of my service from a .json file.

This is what I have so far. Eventually the config values will make it to the log, but not before the rest of the function is executed.

```
getService()
{
    var service = new Service();        

    this.http.get('./config.json')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => this.config = data,
    err => console.log(err) );

    service.ValueA = this.config.ValueA;

    return service;
}
```

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could preload your service leveraging the `APP_INITIALIZER` service at the application startup. The application will wait for the returned promise to be resolved before actually starting.

Here is a sample:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  { provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: (service:Service) => () => service.init(),
    deps:[Service, HTTP_PROVIDERS], multi: true
  }
]);
```

The `load` method would like something like that:

```
@Injectable()
export class Service {
  ValueA:string;

  constructor(private http:Http) {
  }

  init() {
    var promise = this.http.get('config.json').map(res => res.json()).toPromise();
    promise.then(config => this.ValueA = config.ValueA);
    return promise;
  }
}
```

Doing that you will be able to inject the `Service` service and use directly configuration properties like `ValueA`.

Here is a sample within a component:

```
@Component({
  (...)
  providers: [ Service ]
})
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(private service:Service) {
    console.log(`[config] ValueA = ${service.ValueA}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for that. I'm getting a  "No provider for Service! (Token Application Initializer -> Service)" from the chrome console. Any ideas?